# Fill GridView with IENumerable objects

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an object which looks like this:

```
public class TestData
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public string Phone {get; set;}
}
```

I have 10 instances of that class stored in a `IENumerable`.

I also have a `GridView` in my `aspx` file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

What i need is a way to display the contents of the `IENumerable` in the `GridView`. But i want to be able to set the "titles" in the `thead` of the table myself.

So that i get something like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
    <th>Email address</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- the values from each TestData class stored in the IENumberable -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can i do this with a `GridView` or is it better to use some other control for the job? I also remember something about Templating? Not sure, i'm pretty new to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bound field with explicit `HeaderText` of the bound field.
Use auto generate columns to false.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumn="false">
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName " HeaderText="Last Name" />
    .....
</asp:GridView>
```

### Edit 1

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumn="false">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName " HeaderText="Last Name" />
    .....
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks, i understand the `BoundField`, but i'm still not sure how i can bind my `IENumerable` to the gridview. All i can find is info on how to connect it to a database. Any idea how i can bind my `IENumerable` to it?

Comment: I am also getting this error: **GridView' does not have a public property named 'BoundField'**

Comment: @Vivendi I am sorry it should be inside column tag. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. About the "binding an object to the grid", Here is how i did that (for anyone else who needs it): I created a `List` which contains an instance of my `TestData` class. I added the list to the GridView like this: `GridView1.DataSource = myList; GridView1.DataBind();` --- Everything is working now :)